# Array .map only on elements that fit a .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to loop through an array and update elements in place. I only want to loop through elements that fit a filter. How would I do this?

naive approach:

```
arr.forEach(element => {
    if (element.val > 5) {
         element = 9;
    }
});
```

I expect that with .map and .filter I should be able to do this more efficiently and inline.

Comment: you can filter the array first and then map it - arr.filter(...).map(...)

Comment: `arr.filter(x => x > 5).map(x => 9)`... although I'm not sure why you'd want this...

Comment: and which way do you need it? with a new array or mutate the old array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of `filter()`, just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like the following:

```js
var arr = [5, 10, 15]
arr = arr.map(element => element > 5? element = 9 : element);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks for an "in place" update, this approach updates the existing array:

```js
let arr = [20, 5, 6, 1];
arr.forEach((e, i) => { if (e > 5) arr[i] = 9; })    
console.log(arr)
```

Now, the question actually also asks for an approach that only loops through the items that match a filter, but that seems superfluous, since *something* has to loop through every element.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care much about performance and want to have a little fun:

```
Array.prototype.mutate = function (cb) {
    var updates = {};
    this.forEach(function (element, index) {
        var wrapper = {
            value: function () {
                return element;
            },
            update: function (value) {
                updates[index] = value;
            }
        };
        cb(wrapper, index);
    });
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(updates).forEach(function (index) {
        var value = updates[index];
        self[index] = value;
    });
};

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

a.mutate(function (wrapper) {
    if (wrapper.value() % 2 === 0) {
        wrapper.update(wrapper.value() * 2);
    }
});

console.log(a); //[ 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9, 20 ]
```